# Flexbox column inside flexbox row, but only for tablet version

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

I am building a website with 3 designs, depending on the screen width.
My html/php file contains the content in the following order (relating to the picture): B, A, C.
[Link to responsive layout blocks picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd0JV.png)

**Phone:** This is the same order as desired for the phone version, so that version is easily solved.

**Desktop:** I use one div that wraps around all 3 parts; with `display: flex` in combination with the `order` property I was able to generate the desktop version, so that one was also easily solved.

**Tablet:** But unfortunately I can’t get the tablet version working. When I wrap a div around A and C the desired tablet layout is easily obtained, but then it is not possible anymore to put B in between them for the desktop version (even if the CSS media query for the desktop does not mention that specific div).

**My question:** Is it possible to put a flexbox column inside flexbox row, but only for the tablet version?
I have tried several things with the `flex-direction` and `align-items` properties, but haven’t succeeded unfortunately. Maybe it is not possible?

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when the website is visited from a **phone** or **tablet** with plain js:

```js
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Or use a **3rd party library** such as **[wurfl.io](https://web.wurfl.io/#wurfl-js)** to detect only **tablet** users:

```
if (WURFL.is_mobile === true && WURFL.form_factor === "Tablet") {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I am going to try this.